# Assign new tasks to forked() processes

Tags: c, multiprocessing, signals, fork

I need to create a multi-process program that:

1. Creates 5 processes using `fork()`;
2. Sends stuff to do the the child processes using pipes
3. When a child process completes its stuff, it should receive new stuff to do from parent process until all stuff are completed.

Right now my idea is to `wait()` on completed child tasks (and it exits) and then to create a new child process so I always have a maximum of 5 processes.

Is there a way to "re-use" the already existing process? Maybe "signaling" something? Cannot find it on Google.

Using C.

Comment: You already have a pipe between the processes. *Try* to think of a way they could communicate.

Comment: It would probably be easier to multithread and have a thread-safe job queue, unless there is a specific reason to use processes instead.

Comment: @gtzw I have to use processes with fork() as a request.

Comment: @EOF pipe is unidirectional, I could create another pipe and let the parent waiting on read()? But how could it identify the first available process?

Comment: @Bedo You can do I/O multiplexing with `[p]select()` or `[e]poll()`. Alternatively, all of the children can share the same pipe's write-end and write their pid to it when they are done. There are too many possible answers to your question as asked. Try to narrow it down. Also, the idea that you couldn't find anything related to IPC on google is laughable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem in this way:

- Children write the result of their calculation on a pipe A (this pipe is not blocking). Then they wait their next input on a pipe B (this pipe is blocking).
- Parent loops on all children trying to read something from pipe A (this pipe is not blocking so parent goes on if child didn't send anything). If pipe A contains a result, the parent sends another task to that child on pipe B.

There is a pipe A and a pipe B for each child.

Comment: When you say that the "A" pipes from the children to the parent are non-blocking, do you mean that the parent is polling the pipes? That would be *very* wasteful in terms of CPU usage in the parent. You should use `[p]select()` or `[e]poll()` instead.

Comment: If “polling” means that the parent continues to loop and check the pipes, yes, that’s what I’m doing. Since children’s tasks are long, I added a sleep(1) on parent insidie the loop so it’s not continuing pooling.